# How to restore System/Library Files without Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, restore, python

I fell for the tarp. In an attempt to fix an installation issue with Python and Pygame I read something stupid online telling me to delete this file and that file to completely get rid of python on my machine so I could install it. One of the files was Library/Frameworks/Python and the other was System/Library/Frameworks/Python. Obviously when I tried to reinstall Python it wouldn't let me. So now the real dilemma. I'm even more of an idiot because I've never had any kind of backups. I don't have an external to save backups to anyways so I just never did it. Now I find myself unable to do anything with Python anymore and I can't restore from a backup because I'm stupid. So is there any way I can get python reinstalled again without completely restoring my computer and losing everything I have?

Comment: You can reinstall the operating system without losing your personal files - you'll be given the option to import them during the install process. Boot from the install DVD (if you have it), or download from the App Store and run it from there.

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed a fresh install would lose all my files. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Since 10.7 it has also been possible to [reinstall OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this question - ***Do not under any circumstances attempt to remove the versions of Python that ship with OSX!*** New versions from python.org, MacPorts, and homebrew all install in different locations, and will not interfere with the system versions. The system versions are required for key components of the operating system to run properly, so don't try to upgrade them in place (i.e., don't overwrite `/usr/bin/python`, for example). Anyone telling you to alter or remove the system python is either malicious or very poorly informed.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer so I can accept it. I just used the cmd+r upon logging in and reinstalled Lion. Granted it took all day to fix but it works now.